# Как получить названия файлов сгенерированных webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, frontend

**Мне на nodejs сервере, нужно указать в ответе, путь до нужного файла из сборки webpack.**

Там в сборке есть несколько бандлов, и если пользователь запросил например страницу 'test', то в ответе мне нужно отдать страницу к которой будет подключаться скрипт для страницы 'test' исходник этого скрипта имеет имя 'test'.

Сборка webpack генерирует файлы js и кладёт их в папку build, путь до которой я знаю. Часть названия файлов соответствуют входным файлам, их я тоже знаю. Но в конце названия файлов webpack добавляет уникальных хэш из цифр, для того, что файлы правильно кэшировались в браузере. И с одной стороны из-за этого хэша в конце я не могу нормально подключить скрипт т.к. он постоянно меняется и я его заранее не знаю. А с другой стороны, я не могу выпилить этот числовой хэш т.к. без него, браузер закэширует файл, и при следующей пересборке его не обновит.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать? Как мне в node.js получить путь к файлам сгенерённым webpack или хотя бы хэши ?**

Comment: ничего не понятно, но понятно, что вы делаете что-то не так. Во первых - хеш можно передавать как гет параметр, тогда кеширования тоже не должно быть. Во вторых, почему вы html не генерируете в самом вебпаке? он бы тогда сразу подставлял правильные названия файлов

Comment: @ThisMan
1. Можно гет параметром, но тогда нужно через nodejs получать данные о файле, его размер или дату создания и на их основе генерить хэш, не хочется это делать при каждом запросе. Или есть другой вариант?
2. Насчёт html, да, ситуация у меня немного специфичная, мне нужно получить пути до файлов именно в js коде на сервере т.к. там в зависимости от запроса, нужно разные файлы подключать.

Comment: можно плагин написать ( ну или думаю уже есть ), который соберет список всех файлов сгенеренных ( вебпак их даже выводит по идее )
либо можно искать по какому-то шаблону, файлы же все равно генерятся типо
[filename][hash].[ext] вот искать по filename, игнорируя hash. Через регулярки ( но это медленно и плохо )

Comment: Да написали уже плагин https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-manifest-plugin